# TimeZoneInfo incrementing the timezone an hour early on Nov 2nd 2014 EST 2 AM

Tags: c#, datetime, time, timezone

Below is the method I use that takes in three inputs:

`dateTimeInput` which is a string that represents a date.

`inputFormat` are my format strings like this format: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz`.

`timeZoneStandardName` are unique timezone identifiers retrieved from `var TimeZoneList = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();` where the ID is retrieved via `timeZoneList.Id`.

I mainly used `TimeZoneInfo` to get my hours and minute offsets because it's very explicit as to what city/timezone it is, e.g. `UTC` is the input string.

```
public string unixTimeToDateTime(int unixInput, string outputFormat, string timeZoneStandardName)
{
    // output format is "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz"
    TimeZoneInfo objTimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneStandardName);

    if (outputFormat == "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz")
    {
        DateTime UTCDate = Epoch.AddSeconds(unixInput);
        DateTime localDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(UTCDate, objTimeZoneInfo);
        return localDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") + toTimeSpan(objTimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(localDate).Hours, objTimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(localDate).Minutes);
    }
    // output format is anything else
    else
    {
        DateTime UTCDate = Epoch.AddSeconds(unixInput);
        DateTime localDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(UTCDate, objTimeZoneInfo);
        return localDate.ToString(outputFormat);
    }
}
```

---

Using this method on a component in Grasshopper 3D I am going to show you three examples:

One of a DST change on **Mar 9th 2014**

One of a DST change on **Nov 2nd 2014** (which is the date I am having issues with)

And another date on **Nov 2nd 2015** to demonstrate the weird discrepancy.

---

With an input of a list of UTC times (strategically place to force a DST offset on March 9th 2014), and outputting them to EST time, this example successfully outputs with the correct DST offset, as denoted on the most right panel (hint: `2014-03-09T01:00:00-05:00` to `2014-03-09T03:00:00-04:00`).

[image]

---

Now here is the weird part.

If I do the November 2nd 2014 DST change, this is the output:

[image]

As you can tell on the most right panel, `01:00:00-05:00` exists TWICE. The desired output should go from `01:00:00-04:00` to `01:00:00-05:00`!

---

As a comparison, here's November 2nd 2015:

[image]

November 2nd 2015 (which has the same DAYS though not years) has no problem switching DST without repeating an hour.

---

So my conclusion here is that for 2014, November 2nd, the DST increments an hour too early.

Is this a bug of `DateTimeInfo`? Why is it incrementing an hour too early? Is it my code? What gives?!

---

EDIT:

Using the Unixtimestamps and converting them to DateTime:

`1414904400` is `Sun, 02 Nov 2014 05:00:00 GMT`

[image]

`1414908000` is `Sun, 02 Nov 2014 06:00:00 GMT`

[image]

Comment: The 1am to 2am hour occurs twice on November 2, 2014, so it makes sense that the hour is appearing twice. Are you sure your results aren't correct?

Comment: If that's true wouldn't the Nov 2nd 2015 example do the same? I provided that example because I thought it was correct too, but it doesn't make sense since UTC never repeats itself.

Comment: No. November 2nd 2015 is not the "fall back" date for 2015-- November 1st is.

Comment: Right, but `22:00:00-04:00` to `22:00:00-05:00` doesn't repeat when converted to UTC <- 2015 example. The 2014 example repeats through `01:00:00-05:00` and `01:00:00-05:00`.

Comment: Yes, UTC times do not repeat, but local times do (you're converting the UTC times *to* local right?). You're converting two UTC times that happen to both convert to 1AM on November 2nd, 2014. This does not happen on November 2nd 2015 since the DST switchover time is not on that day at 1 AM.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced, sorry :/. I think there's something wrong with my code, but I'll relay the answers as soon as I fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you have:

```
objTimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(localDate)
```

Try instead:

```
objTimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(UTCDate)
```

From [the remarks on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396378%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  (emphisis mine):

> If the dateTime parameter's `Kind` property does not correspond to the time zone object, this method performs the necessary conversion before returning a result. For example, this can occur if the Kind property is `DateTimeKind.Local` but the time zone object is not the local time zone. ***If dateTime is ambiguous, or if the converted time is ambiguous, this method interprets the ambiguous time as a standard time.*** If dateTime is invalid, this method returns a `TimeSpan` object that reflects the difference between UTC and the time zone's standard time.

Comment: I will do this when I go back to work tomorrow :). Thanks Matt!

Comment: This was the answer!! Does this mean switching everything that had `objTimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(localDate)` to `objTimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(UTCDate)`?

Comment: Hi @Matt, one last quick question: http://puu.sh/7MGWn/cd1d34e528.png That is my `DateTimeToUnixTime()` method. At this moment, it uses `localDate` as the input to `objTimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(..)`. Based on my unit testing, I am unable to see any discrepancies, however, for consistencies sake, should `result` be used or `localDate`?

Comment: As an example, here are my unit tests for these two methods: http://puu.sh/7MTB3/4068e06c64.png It so far passed every single one.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for branching in your method.  The first branch looks like what you should return regardless of format.  I think in the second branch you are trying to adjust the output integer by the local offset?  If so, you probably shouldn't do that.  Unix timestamps are *always* expressed in UTC.